# How to convert string to bigInteger and store in hashset?

Tags: java

I had taken n string then I convert it into BIgInteger after that I store it into HashSet But it showing runtime error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

My code is:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.text.*; 
import java.math.*; 
import java.util.regex.*; 
class ex { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); int n = in.nextInt();          
         HashSet<BigInteger> hs=new HashSet<BigInteger>(); 
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { 
              String str=in.nextLine(); 
              BigInteger bi=new BigInteger(str); 
              hs.add(bi); 
         } 
         Iterator itr=hs.iterator(); 
         while(itr.hasNext()) 
         System.out.println(itr.next()); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: SO is not a message board, and you shouldn't be trying to explain your question in its own comments (and ***certainly*** don't try to add code there).  Instead, [edit] your question to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in.next()` instead of `in.nextLine()` and don't forget to close the `Scanner` object `in`.

Here's the complete `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    HashSet<BigInteger> hs = new HashSet<BigInteger>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       String str = in.next();
       BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(str);
       hs.add(bi);
   }
   Iterator<BigInteger> itr = hs.iterator();
   while (itr.hasNext())
     System.out.println(itr.next());
   in.close();
}
```